# Run Command on Mac (Unix) using Java - Stuck

Tags: java, tar

I'm trying to run a "tar" command from Java on Mac. I notice the command get stuck. Bascally, the files size doesn't grow and command doesn't return. However, if I run on smaller directiry, it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
 try
         {
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

             Process process = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"tar","-cvzf",compressFileName+" "+all_dirs}).start();

             InputStream stdin2 = process.getInputStream();
             InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stdin2);
             BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
             String line2 = null;
             System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
             while ( (line2 = br2.readLine()) != null)
                 System.out.println(line2);
             System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
             int exitVal3 = process.waitFor();
             System.out.println("Process exitValue .....: " + exitVal3);
         } catch (Throwable t)
           {
             t.printStackTrace();
           }
```

I also tried:

```
String tile_command="tar -cvzf file.tar.gz dire_to_compress ";
         String[]  tile_command_arr= new String[]{"bash","-c",tile_command};

 try
         {
             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

             Process proc2 = rt.exec(tile_command_arr);
             InputStream stdin2 = process.getInputStream();
             InputStreamReader isr2 = new InputStreamReader(stdin2);
             BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(isr2);
             String line2 = null;
             System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");
             while ( (line2 = br2.readLine()) != null)
                 System.out.println(line2);
             System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
             int exitVal3 = process.waitFor();
             System.out.println("Process exitValue for tiling .....: " + exitVal3);
         } catch (Throwable t)
           {
             t.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Comment: How big is the directory? How much memory is your JVM limited to ?

Comment: This doesn't seem as if it should be working at all, for any directory. Are you sure you are getting a zero exit value for *any* input?

Comment: Directory size is 10GB ... I didn't specify memory parameters when I run Java

Comment: Why? what is the problem with this code?

Comment: But notice, when I run the command from the command line, it works fine.

Comment: But do you get any good results when you run this particular code?

Comment: Yes .. so that is my question.

Comment: Can you give the value of `compressFileName` and `all_dirs` for a case that gets stuck, and a case that succeeds?

Comment: compressFileName just have the name of my the tra.gz file, like file.tar.gz and  all_dirs specify the directory to compress.

Comment: But can you please add an example of input that succeeds and input that fails to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93839/discussion-between-user836026-and-realskeptic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"tar","-cvzf",compressFileName+" "+all_dirs})
```

is especially problematic.

You can't slap two arguments together with a space using ProcessBuilder and expect the underlying process to get two arguments.  It will get one, just as if you ran the command

```
tar -cvzf 'compressFileName all_dirs'
```

which will have tar wondering why you have a really funky file name to create `compressFileName(space)all_dirs`, and where are the contents you want to put in it?

You need something closer to

```
String[]{"tar", "-cvzf", compressFileName, all_dirs};
```

or if `all_dirs` is more than one directory, you need to add them to the String array one at a time (by using an ArrayList of Strings and then pulling the array out of the ArrayList).

Comment: Btw you don't need to say "new String[] {...}": just pass each string as a separate argument as the constructor takes varargs.